# eclipse build.gradle has a red slash through it, what does that mean?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle, egit

I'm running Eclipse - Indigo and have a project configured for EGit that uses Gradle to build.  Today I noticed in the Package Explorer of eclipse, the build.gradle file now has a little red slash through its icon:

[image: build.gradle red slash]

Where did the little red slash come from and what does it mean?  Is it an egit thing (I don't think so, the file doesn't show up in git status from the command line nor does this red slashy icon appear in Preferences, Team, Git, Label Decorations)?  I never noticed it before today, which leads me to believe that it hasn't showed up until today.

EDIT:  Is there any chance .gitignore is contributing to confusion in eclipse?  Here's the contents of my .gitignore
    /test-output
    /logs

```
# Gradle
.gradle
/build

# OSX
.DS_Store

# Eclipse
.classpath
.project
.tomcatplugin
.settings/
/work
/bin

# Emacs backup files
*~
\#*\#/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red slash is a Groovy-Eclipse thing.  It means that the gradle build file is being interpreted as a groovy file, but this groovy file is not on the build path (and this makes sense because gradle build files are not typically in source folders).

Is something not working, or are you just curious about the overlay?

Comment: There is some merit to this explanation, except its not a Groovy Project and I don't have Eclipse's preferences set to treat the build.gradle file as a groovy file.  I have, however, selected "Open With, Groovy Editor" on the build.gradle file, so maybe eclipse now thinks the two are bound at the hip?  In any event, if this is correct there is little I can do about it (except complain to the groovy plug-in people?  The file is fine, the plug-in doesn't like it).  Thanks for the clue and I'll follow up when I know more.

Comment: Oh, yeah, everything is working, I am just curious about the overlay.

Comment: That's it...kind of.  In a Java project, build.gradle gets decorated with a red slash thing.  In a groovy project it doesn't get the red slash thing, but eGit doesn't know its under version control.  Methinks eGit and the Groovy plug in are slugging it out and gradle is coming up as the neglected child in the middle.

Comment: What kind of behavior would you expect?

Comment: I would not expect that the Groovy decorations on the package explorer to decorate a Groovy files that isn't considered source of the project.  My thinking is that I control what's on the build path and what isn't and I think Groovy plug-in is over-reaching here second guessing that decision.  I now have a file in my project that is under Version Control but I can't see that in the Package Explorer because the Groovy plug-in believes it knows better (if indeed that plug-in is to blame; I haven't definitely proven this).  Its no biggie, I can work with this.

Comment: I can see the confusion.  This would have worked better for you if the egit decorator would have superceded the groovy decorator.  Just so you know, Java files not on the build path are displayed with a different icon as well (no decorator is used, but same basic idea).